# how to unregister move modifier in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

i used move modifier on sprite but when i move background and also that sprite out of the screen it automatically comes back on the screen how i unregistered it

```
LoopEntityModifier bucket2 =
    new LoopEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier( 
        new MoveModifier(1.5f, 0, 290.9f,270.0f , 210.0f),
        new MoveModifier(1.5f, 290.9f,0,220.0f , 270.0f))); // // new ScaleModifier(2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
    buckt[2].registerEntityModifier(bucket2);
```

Note: I used this code to unregister but it does not unregister

```
buckt[2].unregisterEntityModifier(bucket2);
```

Comment: Where do you have this piece of code : `buckt[2].unregisterEntityModifier(bucket2);`? Logically, you are ought to vae this inside the function call : `onAreaTouched `.

Otherwise, you could call `clearEntityModifiers();` in the `onAreaTouched` of your sprite. This will kill all modifiers you registered to the sprite (so your `pathmodifier` but also any `AlphaModifier` or else).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we saw you use LoopModifier. So, inside this, all modifier runs reapeatedly because you don't set the loop number. To run once write code like:

```
LoopEntityModifier bucket2 =
new LoopEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier( 
    new MoveModifier(1.5f, 0, 290.9f,270.0f , 210.0f),
    new MoveModifier(1.5f, 290.9f,0,220.0f , 270.0f)),1);
```

**Here 1 is value to assign ,how many time the loop runs.**

To  unregister a Modifier  individually ,  you need  to implements listener in the modifier individually. Like

Declare a Modifier Globally. Then implements listener with it.

```
private MoveModifier aTestModifier;
    public void test() {

     aTestModifier = new MoveModifier(2f, 10, 100, 50, 50,
            new IEntityModifierListener() {

                @Override
                public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                        IEntity pItem) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onModifierFinished(
                        IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                    // unregister your modifier 
                    unregisterEntityModifier(aTestModifier);

                    // same for all other modifier
                }
            });
}
```

same for all other modifier. :)