# How to stop the move Modifier in AndEngine?

Tags: andengine

Here's the method I used to move a sprite in X-axis

```
public void moveX(float constanttime,float fromX,int toX,final Sprite s){
    MoveXModifier mod2=new MoveXModifier(constanttime, fromX, toX);
    s.registerEntityModifier(mod2);
}
```

I'm calling this method like this when I want to start moving the sprite.

```
moveX(5, car1.getX(), -100, car1);
```

(car1 is the sprite I want to move)

I want to stop moving this sprite when the user touches the sprite(car1).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can't pause it, but you can unregister. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829124/how-to-unregister-move-modifier-in-andengine

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can pause entity modifiers (and all updates regarding specific entities individually). The following code allows you to pause an entity's updates based on a boolean value manipulated via touch events (not registered to the scene in the snippet). The following code snippet will cause modifiers on the entity to pause until isActionUp() is called. You can effectively pause entity updates (modifiers) by overriding the onManagedUpdate() method of an entity and passing a value of 0, which tells the entity 0 seconds have passed and to not update the entity modifiers.

```
boolean isTouched = false;

final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, mResourceManager.getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager()){

    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
            isTouched = true;
        }

        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()){
            isTouched = false;
        }

        return super
                .onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        if(isTouched){
            super.onManagedUpdate(0);
        } else {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        }

    }

};
```